# Parsing a large table into smaller tables

Tags: sorting, lua, lua-table

I'm attempting to take a table, that contains numerous nested tables, and place them into an order based on certain Y-coordinate & object type values.  I want to take this "master" table and sort them in Y-location first, then sort it dependent on types (text or lines).

Right now, all I can think of doing is to place two tables that consist of objects that are above and below point 200 on a Y-axis.  From that, two tables that are split into two different object types; lines and text.

I cannot seem to get beyond a certain point in my code where I have the same `for` loops occurring for each table.  I do this in order to maintain a point of "top to bottom" with the objects of each type.  Ideally, I wish to maintain the following order for my table(s) (and hopefully placed into the larger table for use):

< 201 for text

< 201 for lines

> 200 for text
>
> 200 for lines

Here is what I have so far (where `objTable` is my master table containing all of the numerous objects, where each of those is a table of their own):

```
local offset = 0
local upperObjTbl, lowerObjTbl, upperLineTbl, lowerLineTbl = {},{},{},{}
for objKey, object in pairs(objTable) do
    if tonumber(object.y) < 201 and object.object ~= "line" then
       offset = totalOffset + object.offset
       table.insert(lowerObjTbl, #lowerObjTbl + 1, object)
    end
end
for objKey, object in pairs(objTable) do
    if tonumber(object.y) < 201 and object.object == "line" then
       offset = totalOffset + object.offset
       table.insert(lowerObjTbl, #lowerObjTbl + 1, object)
    end
end         
for objKey, object in pairs(objTable) do
    if tonumber(object.y) > 200 and object.object ~= "line" then
       offset = totalOffset + object.offset
       table.insert(higherObjTbl, #higherObjTbl + 1, object)
    end
end
for objKey, object in pairs(objTable) do
    if tonumber(object.y) > 200 and object.object == "line" then
       offset = totalOffset + object.offset
       table.insert(higherObjTbl, #higherObjTbl + 1, object)
    end
end
```

Ideally, what I would like to happen is to compact this into a much better `for` loop that, no matter what type of object it is or where on the Y-axis it is located, it places them in order of Y-axis first (lowest to highest) and text before lines.

Comment: Have you tried ```table.sort```

Comment: I am trying it but continually get errors in return.  I'm having difficulty understanding `table.sort`.  I've read a lot of similar threads where the poster(s) was advised to use something similar to `table.sort(table, function(a,b) return a<b end)` and also place all of the tables in my `objTable` first into another table and then sort it with the keys created by inserting them all into a new table.  But I'm still having issues with figuring this out.  Any further tips or advice is and will be greatly appreciated!